# Create object from URL

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to create an object / blob object from URL like this:

```
blob:http://127.0.0.1:8888/4bd9114b-1adb-40ce-b55b-a38f803b849a
```

and like this: `blob:111d6876-dc9c-4ec5-84a1-1004cae101b4`

Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', source, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      alert('Response status - ' + this.status);    
      if (this.status == 200) {
        var myBlob = this.response;
        alert("Converted to Blob");
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

But the response is always `this.status` is `0`

**Update:**

The blob came from the clipboard

Comment: Could you be more specific and provide some examples. What is the initial data and what should the output look like?

Comment: Where do you get the blob from? Database, filesystem.. what you provided are (urlencoded) strings. Basically, you can turn anything into objects

Comment: @DanFromGermany The blob came from the clipboard, so its purely client-side.

Comment: Your code is right, your url is either invalid or doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a start, it should answer for the first url you specified.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob
and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

```
var blobPart=["http%3A//127.0.0.1%3A8888/4bd9114b-1adb-40ce-b55b-a38f803b849a"];

var blob = new Blob(blobPart, {type: "application/octet-binary"}); // pass a useful mime type here
console.log("blob ~ ", blob);

var urlObj = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
console.log("url ~", urlObj);

 //using FileReader to read Blob

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
   console.log("reader result ~ ",reader.result); 
});

reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

See console: http://jsfiddle.net/Seandeburca/P9HRa/